# Installing java 1.8 from supermarket

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to use community cookbook from supermarket for java 1.8.2 installation from `https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java/versions/1.8.2` .
I have added the dependency in metadata.rb and added in berksfile as well. Added `include_recipe` in recipe and when I run I get the following error. I checked there is no yum repo configured not sure if its because of that. Also what if java 1.8 is already installed on the endpoint will it still install this?

```
 * yum_package[java-1.6.0-openjdk] action install[2018-01-19T04:22:52-05:00] INFO: Processing yum_package[java-1.6.0-openjdk] action install (java::openjdk line 93)

    * No candidate version available for java-1.6.0-openjdk
    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `install` on resource 'yum_package[java-1.6.0-openjdk]'
    ================================================================================

    Chef::Exceptions::Package
    -------------------------
    No candidate version available for java-1.6.0-openjdk

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/java/recipes/openjdk.rb

     93:   package pkg do
     94:     action :install
     95:     notifies :create, "ruby_block[update-java-alternatives]", :immediately if platform?("ubuntu","debian","redhat","centos","fedora","scientific","amazon")
     96:   end
     97: end

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/java/recipes/openjdk.rb:93:in `block in from_file'

    yum_package("java-1.6.0-openjdk") do
      package_name "java-1.6.0-openjdk"
      action [:install]
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      declared_type :package
      cookbook_name "java"
      recipe_name "openjdk"
      flush_cache {:before=>false, :after=>false}
    end

    System Info:
    ------------
    chef_version=12.21.26
    platform=redhat
    platform_version=7.4
    ruby=ruby 2.3.5p376 (2017-09-14 revision 59905) [x86_64-linux]
    program_name=chef-client worker: ppid=3118;start=04:22:48;
    executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client
```

Answer (score 0):

To install openjdk 1.8 you should use latest java cookbook version (`1.50.x`, not `1.8.2`). Cookbook version does not match java version.

In your recipe, you should put the following code:

```
node.default["java"]["install_flavor"] = "openjdk"
node.default["java"]["jdk_version"]    = "8"

include_recipe "java"
```